# Fill radio button group with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, console-application

I have simply pdf form (generated from Adobe Acrobat - [test_pdf](http://www68.zippyshare.com/v/9GmTEBIC/file.html)) with two editable textboxes and one radio button group with 3 options.

[image]

How I can choose the correct option and mark this on pdf template?
When I set radiobutton fields as below:

```
        string pdfTemplate = @"c:\Temp\PDF\fw4.pdf";
        string newFile = @"c:\Temp\PDF\completed_fw4.pdf";

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", "test1");
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text2", "test2");

        var radiobuttons = pdfFormFields.GetAppearanceStates("Group3");
        foreach (string rb in radiobuttons)
        {
            if (rb != "Off")
            {
                if (rb == "Wybór1")
                {
                    pdfFormFields.SetField(rb, "On");
                }
                else
                {
                    pdfFormFields.SetField(rb, "Off");
                }
            }
        }

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.Close();
```

unfortunately always last button is set as 'On' (I would like to set first button in this example).

How I should construct 'foreach' loop?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

```
    string pdfTemplate = @"c:\Temp\PDF\fw4.pdf";
    string newFile = @"c:\Temp\PDF\completed_fw4.pdf";

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
    AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

    pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", "test1");
    pdfFormFields.SetField("Text2", "test2");
    pdfFormFields.SetField("Group3", "Wybór1"); // it's only 1 line

    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.Close();
```